# Is there a way to intercept the loading of a react-native bundle?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm currently trying to put together a new react-native app and I need the react-native bundle to be encrypted when it's pushed to the device and while it lives on it. I then need to be able to decrypt it before it's loaded by the native code else it'll be gibberish.

Is there some way to intercept the loading of the bundle such that I can achieve this? I've googled around and done research and there doesn't really seem to be much in the way of answers to this. I'd need ways for both Android and iOS ideally (I'm assuming this will need to be a native code solution), but if a way is found for one, I would imagine the same principles could be applied for the other.

Some detail if it might be helpful: currently using `0.63.2` of react-native (non-expo). Native and even jni-based solutions welcomed - I'd rather have a solution than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, like codepush (https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push) loads the bundle through downloading the bundle and "installing" it before the app launch.

You can manipulate the bundle loading in the files `ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.m` and `android/app/src/main/java/com/MyApp/MainApplication.java` overriding some methods.

But regardless about that, even if you encrypt the bundle, if the key to decrypt is on the front-end app aside the js bundle, it will always has a way to decrypt. Maybe it require some time, but it's possible.

So, is this encryption very necessary? Maybe using the new Hermes Js https://github.com/facebook/hermes there is some obfuscation on the bundle and it's already enough.